# Keep current indentation in Visual Studio (Python) on Enter?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2012

Each time I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in Visual Studio (Python), I go to the next line. But instead of keeping the current indentation, the cursor goes to the leftmost margin:

[image]

This is really annoying. Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: It looks like you've hit Enter twice, so VS has assumed you've finished with that function.

Comment: Yes, in this picture but not in reality.

Comment: So you just typed ...`t`-`(`-`i`-`)`-`<Enter>`? Have you tried looking at the indentation options in the settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Visual Studio go to:

Tool->Options->Text Editor->All Languages->Tabs

and set the Indenting options to Smart.

Comment: What would the `block` setting mean in regards to Python? In other languages it'd mean keeping the indent where the `{` and `}` are right?